# Record audio over a live video

Tags: ios, ipad, audio-recording

I have a video file and I want to suppress the audio of the video file while playing and record my own audio through my iPad application. Can anyone suggest me the ways to achieve it?

Comment: Do you mean mute the player & overlay with your own sound track? What does your `record` mean ?

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve it?. If yes can you brief me on that?